# pandas create a DataFrame by multiplying every element in a list with every other element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to populate a dataframe with a matrix built from a single list, but the math and python syntax are beyond me.  I essentially need to perform some math operations as if the same list were both the rows and the columns.

So it should look something like this....

```
#Input
list = [1,2,3,4]

create a matrix using some math on the list, like matrix[i,j] = list[i] * list[j]

#output
np.matrix([[1,2,3,4], [2,4,6,8], [3,6,9,12], [4,8,12,16]])

df = pd.dataframe[np.matrix]
```

Comment: Have you read the docs!?

Answer (score 2):

Broadcasted multiplication will work here:

```
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
pd.DataFrame(arr * arr[:,None])    

   0  1   2   3
0  1  2   3   4
1  2  4   6   8
2  3  6   9  12
3  4  8  12  16
```

Alternatively, most numpy arithmetic functions define an `.outer` unfunc:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.multiply.outer(arr, arr))

   0  1   2   3
0  1  2   3   4
1  2  4   6   8
2  3  6   9  12
3  4  8  12  16
```

Comment: That worked great.  Is there a way to name the columns of the dataframe as you using this approach?  Or would it be better to name it after the dataframe has been populated?

Comment: @UserBRy You can name the columns while creating them: `pd.DataFrame(np.multiply.outer(arr, arr), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])`

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [1,2,3,4]
```

Nested for loops would work:

```
import numpy as np
a = []
for n in data:
    row = []
    for m in data:
        math = some_operation_on(m,n)
        row.append(math)
    a.append(row)

a = np.array(a)
```

For simple operations like your example use [numpy.meshgrid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html#numpy.mgrid).

```
In [21]: a = [1,2,3,4]

In [22]: x,y = np.meshgrid(a,a)

In [23]: x*y
Out[23]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 2,  4,  6,  8],
       [ 3,  6,  9, 12],
       [ 4,  8, 12, 16]])
```